# javascript make div go blank by clicking outside it

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, html

I have a number of search/text boxes that, using AJAX, search database tables and place results/search suggestions in a div similar to google search.  Right now other than reloading the page there is no way to empty these divs.  I would like to make it so that if you backspace to make the textbox blank as in google search, the div empties out. Right now when you backspace all the way it treats it as searching on "" and returns all the results.  Or alternatively let you click outside the box to empty it.  Otherwise I am ending up with filled divs on the page which clutters it up.  I am thinking I either need to do change query so that if the string is empty it returns nothing or something with javascript if you click outside the box the box goes empty.  Thanks for any suggestion:

Here is abbreviated code:

Javascript

```
function getHints(str) {
...
document.getElementById("results").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;//places output in results div
...
xmlhttp.open("GET","search.php?searchterm="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

html

```
<input type="text" id="search" onkeyup="getHints(this.value)">Search<div id="results"></div>
```

php

```
$str = $_REQUEST['str'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%$str%'";
search database and echo out results.
```

Comment: Please check that google uses `HASHCHANGE` Event. and on key up the hash is set accordingly. So that history can repeat itself :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check for an empty string and process accordingly:

```
function getHints(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementsById("results").innerHTML = "";
    }
    else {
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Now when you backspace to empty out div, this keeps it from displaying all results but does not empty out text previously written to div.  Do I need another event handler?

Comment: @user1260310, this code empties out the results div by setting the innerHTML to an empty string. Is there another div you were expecting to empty out?

Comment: No that is the div.  I guess I can put condition in Php.  Strange it is not working in js

Comment: I put am alert in and it is definitely getting str equal nothing on backspace.  And it is no longer searching on that.  But it is not changing the div.

Answer (score 3):

Use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), it will help you a lot when doing things like this, AJAX, manipulating the DOM etc.

```
function getHints(str) {
    ...
    if (str === "")
    {
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("results").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        ...
        xmlhttp.open("GET","search.php?searchterm="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```